# Is there any way to limit the dex method count with the new d8 compiler?

Tags: android, dex, android-multidex

My app need to limit the method count of the main dex. With the old dex compiler, we can use

```
dexOptions {
    additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    additionalParameters += '--set-max-idx-number=60000'
}
```

But with the new d8 compiler，it doesn't work.
Is there any way to limit the dex method count with the new d8 compiler?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No.According to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/d8),d8 did not provide a corresponding way to achieve this.

Comment: I was not able to find a solution either. However, I tried out the new R8 instead of Proguard, and it optimized the code so much that my project got below the DEX file limit. (for my project: Proguard: 93505 methods, R8: 61182 methods). Using R8 you might not need to limit the dex size anymore if you get below the limit as well.